# How do I set the cardinality of a entity relationship in XCode4?

Tags: core-data, xcode4

Evenings chaps,

I'm using XCode4 to model my entities, but I cannot figure out how to change the cardinality of the relationships so by default they are all 1 to 1 relationships. Someone give me a hint on how to change it please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you seeing a straight line with one arrowhead? That's 1:1 already and is the default.

To set 1:many, one way is to select the relationship and in the right view pane (you may need to turn it on by clicking the right hand button in the view section in the toolbar) select the rightmost of the three icons at the top. You should see some options under "Relationship", including "Plural" (Maybe "Cardinality" was too long).

Comment: Thank you, I'd been hunting all over XCode and Google for half an hour trying to figure this out.  I hate how XCode hides things in the sidebar where I'd never think to look!